# VFX Graph projectile trail shows gaps

Tags: unity, particles, trail-renderer, vfxgraph

I'm learning to use Unity's VFX Graph to create projectiles. One projectile I'm working on is starting to get where I want it to be, but there's an issue where gaps are visible in the trail when I move the game object; this is something I want to avoid.

The game object's transform is bound to a target position property, which I set in in the 'initialize particle' context. I'm also using a `sin` node to alter the velocity of the particles to create a wave effect.

Things I've tried:

- Modifying alpha over life
- Modifying size over life
- Modifying the min & max attributes of the sin node inputs

Nothing seems to work, I thought it's likely I need to use the velocity of the target game obejct with the `sin` node somehow, but I'm not quite sure how.

- Image of my effect so far: [image]
- VFX Graph: [image]
- What I'd like to aim for (sorry the image is low res): [image]

Comment: Have you considered using a [Particle Strip System](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.visualeffectgraph@7.1/manual/Systems.html) for this, instead of individual particle splats? [Strips form ribbons connecting positions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mRQDCIjDHdM), so they're ideal for continuous trails where you don't want to see gaps between segments.

Comment: I briefly looked into the particle strip system but there's very few guides onlne (the one you linked is actually the only one I could find on YouTube) and the documentation is also lacking. I'll have to do some trial and error to figure out how to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented a new *Particle Strip* system, and in the Spawn context, used the "Spawn Over Distance" block. I couldn't get the target position blocks to work like I did with my previous effect, so I simply attached the effect to a parent gameobject. It creates a much smoother trail (no visisble gaps).

VFX Graph: [image]